# Vue Animation Individual floating elements like on Coachella website

Tags: animation, vue.js, carousel

Can anyone point out how to achieve something similar to 
https://www.coachella.com/home/
Social section animation/carousel

Can someone point out how we may create it in a Vue object with the help of transitions and more..

HTML

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
          <div class="cent">
            <button v-on:click="show = !show">Toggle</button>
          </div>
    <div class="cent">
            <transition v-for="block in blocks" :key="block" name="fade">
            <div class="block" v-if="show">
                <p class="els">{{block}}</p>
            </div>
            </transition>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

JS

```
export default {
  name: "app",
  data() {
    return {
      msg: "Welcome to Your Vue.js App",
      show: false,
      blocks: ["element", "fire", "water", "earth", "wind"]
    };
  }
};
```

CSS

```
.els{
  background-color: aqua;
  display: inline-flex;
  padding:20px;
}
.cent{
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.block {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  flex-basis: auto;
}

.fade-enter{

}
.fade-enter-active{
  animation:slideIn 1s ease-out forwards;
}
.fade-leave{

}
.fade-leave-active{
animation:slideOut 1s ease-out forwards;
}

@keyframes slideIn {
  from {
    transform:translateX(100%);
  }

  to {
    transform:translateX(0%);
  }
}

@keyframes slideOut {
  from {
    transform:translateX(0%);
  }

  to {
    transform:translateX(100%);
  }
}
```

Just a basic try to make elements of blocks float... But as said earlier i want to make it float like coachella site.

P.S
I have tried google and other resources like madewithvuejs and others but didn't found anything similar.

Any help would be grateful..